# Laptop with hybrid graphics. Problem with drivers

Tags: 10.04, drivers, nvidia-optimus

I've just installed Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. After booting, system recommended me some drivers for my graphic card (nVidia GT 325M). After installation and reboot all I see is black screen. Recovery mode gives the same effect. I have Windows 7 on the same machine. How can I repair (delete drivers?)? I'm Linux newbie so please, be simple. I also would like to ask is there some working solution for hybrid graphic on Ubuntu? I've read some info on the internet but haven't found any solution and nVidia says they will not provide support for Linux with their hybrid graphics technology.

Answer (score 2):

Hybrid graphics is a bad thing under Linux. Unfortunately there's not a good and easy solution to get 3D acceleration, but I can guide you to remove the Nvidia driver.

1. Boot Ubuntu while holding *Shift* to make sure GRUB fires up
2. Choose to enter in recovery mode, and when prompted, you should choose to boot in safe graphics mode
3. Now you can log in with a low resolution and remove the driver

Comment: It's sad ;/ Who should I accuse for this problem? The nVidia side or Linux? Can u say something more about this problem, cause I'm interested? Should I install some drivers for Intel graphics? Everything seems to work fine, but I'd like to know is it good idea or not?

Comment: Accuse nVidia; they have stated that they have no plans to support Optimus graphics at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Hybrid graphics has improved a bit lately. Have a look at these websites:
 http://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux
 http://linux-hybrid-graphics.blogspot.com/

Bumblebee has an ./install.sh command that does all the installation for you. The fact that is in github is for convenience of rapid development and convenient download. The software is well worked-out and there are over a hundred users who have tested bumblebee, and it's been downloaded more than 70,000 times as of today.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Bumblebee](https://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee) project but as you can see at the link, it's only source code at the moment and has bugs and the assorted usability issues you'd expect with a very new program that uses reverse-engineered commands to do things.

A machine with Optimus is a bad choice if you want to run any Linux-based distro on it, including Ubuntu.